# Sending Events in react native even when app goes in background

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, unity-game-engine, react-hooks

Currently I am implementing events in my react native project based on this page :
https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android#sending-events-to-javascript

My java code looks like:

```
     // show listner.
     private IUnityAdsShowListener showListener = new IUnityAdsShowListener() {
        WritableMap params = Arguments.createMap();
    
        @Override
        public void onUnityAdsShowFailure(String placementId, UnityAds.UnityAdsShowError error, String message) {
           Log.e("UnityAdsExample", "Unity Ads failed to show ad for " + placementId + " with error: [" + error + "] " + message);
           params.putString("adStatus", "adShowFail");
           sendEvent("AD_COMPLETED", params);
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onUnityAdsShowStart(String placementId) {
           Log.v("UnityAdsExample", "onUnityAdsShowStart: " + placementId);
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onUnityAdsShowClick(String placementId) {
           Log.v("UnityAdsExample", "onUnityAdsShowClick: " + placementId);
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onUnityAdsShowComplete(String placementId, UnityAds.UnityAdsShowCompletionState state) {
           Log.v("UnityAdsExample", "onUnityAdsShowComplete: " + placementId);
           if (state.equals(UnityAds.UnityAdsShowCompletionState.COMPLETED)) {
              // User seen full ad
              params.putString("adStatus", "fullComplete");
              sendEvent("AD_COMPLETED", params);
           } else {
              // User skipped the ad
              params.putString("adStatus", "partialComplete");
              sendEvent("AD_COMPLETED", params);
           }
        }
     };
```

And I send events using:

```
  private void sendEvent(String eventName, WritableMap params) {
    reactContext
    .getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class)
    .emit(eventName, params);
  }
```

On javascript part I have:

```
    /* this hook take care for unity ad call backs */
    React.useEffect(async() => {

      const loadEventEmitter = new NativeEventEmitter();
      const showEventEmitter = new NativeEventEmitter();
  
      const loadEventListener = loadEventEmitter.addListener(
        'AD_LOADED', 
        (event) => {
          console.log("Unity Ad loading complete")
          console.log(event.adStatus) // "someValue"
  
          // if time out has occurred than mostly we have started doing mining.
          // now we cannot show ad, so just return from here.
          // we will not call show(), so "EARNED_REWARD", callback won't occur.
          if(showAdTimeOutRef.current){
            setShowAdTimeOut(false)
            return;
          } else {
            setAdIsLoaded(true);
            UnityAdsModule.showAd(); // show unity ad
          }
      });
  
      const showEventListener = showEventEmitter.addListener(
        'AD_COMPLETED', 
        (event) => {
          console.log("Unity Ad showing complete")
          console.log(event.adStatus) // "someValue"

          if(event.adStatus == "fullComplete"){
            console.log("we can start mining now ...")
            setMiningAfterAd(true);
          }
      });

      /* Unsubscribe from events on unmount */
      return () => {
        loadEventListener.remove();
        showEventListener.remove();
      };
  
    }, []);
```

Now my issue is when Ad is played the app goes to background and the "AD_COMPLETED" only get fired when app comes to foreground, I want "AD_COMPLETED" to be fired even when App is in background. Because I want to some task as soon as Ad is completed.

I have seen this behaviour with 'react-native-google-mobile-ads' package for admob ads. Any input on this ?